# What is the reason of this Segmentation fault for PRIME1 on Spoj?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve the PRIME1 problem on [Spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/). I implemented this code using segmented sieve of Eratosthenes

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    long int primes[100000];

    int main(void) {

       long int t, m, n, i, j, p;
       scanf("%ld",&t);

       while(t--) {
          scanf("%ld",&m);
          scanf("%ld",&n);

          for(i=2; i*i<=n; i++) {
            p=m/i;
            p=p*i;

            for(j=p; j<=n; j+=i)    {
                if(j!=i)
                    primes[j-m] = 1;
            }
          }

          for(i=0; i<(n-m+1); i++)  {
             if(primes[i] == 0) 
                 printf("%ld ",i+m);
             else 
                 continue;
          }

          printf("\n");
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Its works fine when value of `n-m` is not very high. But if the value of `n-m` gets very high (i.e. near about 100000), it gives Segmentation fault. Why there is such kind of behaviour?

Also, when I declared the primes array inside main, the code works correctly.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {

       long int t, m, n, i, j, p;
       scanf("%ld",&t);

       while(t--) {
          scanf("%ld",&m);
          scanf("%ld",&n);
          if(m==1)  m=2;

          long int primes[n-m+1];
          for(i=0;i<n-m+1;i++) 
            primes[i]=0;

          for(i=2; i*i<=n; i++) {
            p=m/i;
            p=p*i;

            for(j=p; j<=n; j+=i)    {
                if(j!=i)
                    primes[j-m] = 1;
            }
          }

          for(i=0; i<(n-m+1); i++)  {
             if(primes[i] == 0) 
                 printf("%ld ",i+m);
             else 
                 continue;
          }

          printf("\n");
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Why the program gives Segmentation fault when I declare the primes array globally?

Comment: Maybe you're going out of bounds of the array? Or maybe you need `unsigned long long` (`long` may be just 32 bits and you're overflowing)?

Comment: `n-m` max  = 100000, `i<(n-m+1)` : `i` max = `n-m` but `primes[100000];` So `primes[i]=0;` (`primes[100000] = 1`) is out of bounds.

Comment: when a user runs the program, they are left with a blinking cursor and no idea about what they are expected to enter.   Suggest: prompt the user for each of the three input values.  Always check the returned value from scanf() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @user3629249 This program for SPOJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first you are declaring `primes` to have a fixed size of `100000` so if you ever try to access an element outside that range you'll be accessing memory you should not, thus a seg fault.

In the second example you declare it to be size `n-m+1` which will make sure it's always big enough to do what you want.

Comment: No. Even if the value of n-m is within and near about 100000, for example 99999, it shows a Segmentation fault.

Comment: I can't repoduce the failure if `n-m` is < 100000, I only get a seg fault if it's greater than that